# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"} Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, controller, routes

I have the following going on:

rspec test in users_controller_spec:

```
it "should redirect to the user show page" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
end
```

In my users_controller I have the following:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = @user.name
end

def create
  @title = "Sign up"
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, :notice => "Signed Up!"
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render "new"
  end
end
```

In my routes.rb I have the following:

```
  Psra::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  # Root Route

  root :to => 'pages#home'

  # Pages Routes

  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'

  # Users Route

  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'

  #Sessions Routes
  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"

end
```

And Here is my rake routes

```
       users GET    /users(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
             POST   /users(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
    sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"sessions"}
             POST   /sessions(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
 new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"sessions"}
     session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sessions"}
             PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"sessions"}
             DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
        root        /                            {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
     contact        /contact(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
       about        /about(.:format)             {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
        help        /help(.:format)              {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
      signup        /signup(.:format)            {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
                    /signup(.:format)            {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
      logout GET    /logout(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
       login GET    /login(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
```

This all results in the following error:

```
1) UsersController POST 'create' success should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this working from browser? Not from test

Comment: Yes, it works inside the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like to me that the `show` action isn't getting the user information it needs to get the correct page.  The `assigns` method is just creating an instance variable.  The `user_path` call will need a User mock or object to make the call work correctly.

Comment: my understanding is that assigns takes the :user and converts it to an object. Is that not correct?

Comment: `assigns` doesn't actually return an object. That I believe is the root of the problem.